# Problems with Netgear A6210 High Gain Wi-Fi USB 3.0 Adapter on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I've downloaded driver from here: https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210

And I experience occasional connection loss and most of the time low signal strength but, while on Windows 8.1 none of the above happens.
My router is very close to my PC (on the same table).

Has anyone encountered same problems ? Is there alternative driver available ?

Here is my wireless info [link](https://github.com/zvitr/general/blob/master/wireless-info.txt)

After some investigation it looks like the WiFi adapter is connecting with 802.11 N protocol and not the 802.11 AC on the 5 GHz band, My guess is that the Driver is not supporting it.

Kind regards, Greg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled Beamforming, no more issues.

Beamforming is a technology that estimates the signal direction and focuses the signal to that direction to minimize the waste of a signal that, otherwise, would be spread uniformly in space.
When Source is very close to the destination of a signal - direction estimation works much less accurate and, so there might be signal strength / loss issues.

Comment: Beamforming is an advanced router function that boosts the performance of your wireless network.

Comment: @karel I've edited my answer